# Python class function outside of class yet it calls for a function defined inside the class

Tags: python

In python, what I have is like the following:

```
def func(self):
  self.func2()


class myClass:
  f = func
  def func2():
    ...
```

Then I create an object and call the member function:

```
C = myClass
C.f()
```

This doesn't work, it says `"myClass object has no attribute 'func2'"`.. Can anyone help debug this?

EDIT:
After seeing several suggestions and comments, I decided to post the original code up:

```
def quickSort(self, A, start, end):
    if start < end:
        q = self.partition(A, start, end)
        self.quickSort(A, start, q-1)
        self.quickSort(A, q+1, end)


class SortingAlgo(object):
    qsort = quickSort
    def partition(self, A, start, end):
        x = A[end]
        i = start - 1
        for j in range(start, end):
            if (A[j] <= x):
                i += 1
                A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]
        A[i+1], A[end]= A[end], A[i+1]
        return i+1

A = [5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 7 , -4, 9843]
Sort = SortingAlgo()
```

It's a simple quick sort implementation, I didn't really mean to implement one, I just want to try class features of Python. The above code doesn't work, error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 22, in <module>
    Sort.qsort(A, 0, len(A)-1)
  File "tmp.py", line 4, in quickSort
    self.quickSort(A, start, q-1)
AttributeError: 'SortingAlgo' object has no attribute 'quickSort'
```

I don't think I missed anything everyone mentioned already. So what's wrong with the code?

Comment: I can't reproduce that error.  (It fails because you didn't include a `self` argument for `func2`, but if you put one in then it works.)

Comment: i tried this code on both 2 and 3, with several permutations of bugfixes (you're not actually creating an object, just aliasing the class), and never got that error.  please include your actual code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `self.quickSort()`, but there is no `quickSort` in the class.  You assigned the function to `qsort`, so you need to call `self.qsort()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `self` as argument of `func2`. When calling myClass add `()`.

```
def func(self):
  self.func2()

class myClass:
  f = func
  def func2(self):
    print 'func2'

C = myClass()
C.f()
```